# How to make a KVO observer and feed tableview with MutableArray info?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a problem, Im a starter in iphone programming and I dont know how to do this.
I have to make a KVO observer to know when a textfield is receiving a string and display that strings into a tableview with an animation, I already got the array of strings from the textfield but I dont know how to display it into the tableview. So someones help will be great appreciated!!

Heres my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count); <-- this print works good, also the first one
    [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

And in the tableviewcontroller I only have this (for testing but it does not work :():

```
[self viewdidload];
    if (!self.TasksArray) self.TasksArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.TasksArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"];


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        NSLog(@"number of tasks when tableview:%d", self.TasksArray.count);
            //return self.TasksArray.count;
        return self.TasksArray.count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the object to the  `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`
make sure you call `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count); <-- this print works good, also the first one
    [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

You may also have to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after you assigned the object from the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to `self.TasksArray`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidload];

  if (!self.TasksArray) self.TasksArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  self.TasksArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"];

  [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}   

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  NSLog(@"number of tasks when tableview:%d", self.TasksArray.count);
  return self.TasksArray.count;
}
```

Depending on your app architecture it might be better to call `[self.tableView reloadData]`in `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Whats the synchronize for? I men i dont know what is that hehe, and  the reload data in viewwillappear didnt work, I need that the tableview updates at real time, at the same tame the textfield is returning with a string... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..with textFieldDidEditing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count); <-- this print works good, also the first one
    [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.yourtableview reloadData];

}
```

Hope it helps you..